# Is there a best practice on maintaining thirdparty javascript libraries in Git repo for a Java project (not Node project)?

Tags: javascript, java, git, dependency-management

I am working on a server side Java project. The Java code is merely 4 KB in size. However, the thirdparty JavaScript libraries (chartjs, angular, jquery, d3, etc.) consume a whopping 50 MB.

Right now, the Java code as well as all the thirdparty JavaScript libraries are committed to my git repository. This allows me to just clone the repository, build and run the project.

I would like to know if there is a recommended best practice to manage thirdparty JavaScript libraries?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: You should look into a package/dependency manager, and then check in only the file that declares the dependencies. I've seen bower used, though I haven't used it directly (so I can't vouch for it), and its front page gently nudges viewers towards other dependency managers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right now, the Java code as well as all the thirdparty JavaScript libraries are committed to my git repository. This allows me to just clone the repository, build and run the project.

I think that is the way to go.

When your user will come to you with a bug for his now obsolete version, you want to be able to get the project exactly as it was when you provided the software. If you have to struggle to get the same versions of the libraries your user is using, it is a massive loss of time.

When you decide to update those libraries, it makes sense to update your git repo at the same time.

But that is my opinion.